# mapview refresh

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a mapview in my appn. I show some points on the map when the page gets loaded.
I also have a search button in that page. So after I give something to search and click search button, map doesnt gets refreshed. It gets refreshed only when we touch anywhere on the map. I have given mapview.invalidate() also. Still not working...

Any idea why this problem occurs?

Comment: I have similiar problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have to give..

```
mapview.invalidate()
```

I had some problem while displaying overlays. So it didnt work earlier. Now its perfectly working..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a MapView use the SupportMapFragment

```
       <fragment
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/lite_map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp" />
```

Then init a fragment and get your map with **getMapAsync()** method:

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.lite_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

The next implementation is the same as with a MapView - process a callback method **onMapReady**:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    map = googleMap;

    updateMapCoordinates();

}
```